# Excel Formula: Solve for X where Y * Z% = X, Y and Z are known

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

That was probably a terrible title.

I have required after tax revenue and the expected effective tax rate, I need to know how to calculate the gross revenue required to meet the after tax revenue when the tax rate is factored.

Example

I need 100K in revenue to pay all company expenses.
The tax rate of the company is going to be 20%.
How do I figure out how much revenue I must have, in order to have 100K after 20% is taken out.

Or more specifically, how do I express that in an Excel formula.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a gross margin calculation. Here's a utility I give to my staff, for you the 3rd section should be relevant.  Hope this helps

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your maths, though your Title is incorrect (despite giving a reasonable indication of your requirement!)

Using `X` as your unknown, `Y` as % (expressed as a decimal, so 20% is 0.2) and `Z` as the outcome (100) you could use Solver, as shown:

[image: SO19533397 example]

But this is overkill for what is solvable with a formula. The relationship can be expressed as:

`X` – `X` * `Y` = `Z`

and that can be rearranged as below:

X(1-Y)=Z
X=Z/(1-Y)

With the values in your example:

X=100/(1-0.2)
X=100/0.8

So with `Y` and `Z` in the cells as shown in blue, `X` may be derived with `=C4/(1-B4)` (shown in A4).

Comment: +1 for algebra! "...a little theory and calculation would have saved him ninety per cent of his labor." - Nikola Tesla, on Thomas Edison